# How to call repo path in azure devops pipline for py script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have python script stored on my repo and i'm trying to create pipeline to run it. I have no idea how to ptovide correct path to the repo where it is stored. I receive `no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/vg/main.py'`

repo: `vg`

yaml:

```
steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath' # Options: filePath, inline
    scriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/vg/main.py # Required when scriptSource == filePath
    #script: # Required when scriptSource == inline
    arguments: $(file_path) $(pat) $(organization) $(project) $(vg_name)
    #pythonInterpreter: # Optional
    #workingDirectory: # Optional
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
- bash: python $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/vg/main.py
- script: python $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/poc/main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your only repo it is downloaded directly to source folder so your script should be here `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/main.py`

Please check this [checkout path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path) section to understand how and where source code is downloaded.